# Replace select option lists with HTML list

Tags: jquery

For the design of my website I want to replace any select input types with a HTML menu with jQuery. I know there are some default plugins which do exactly that, but that is so many lines of code, I believe it can be done with way less code (and I want to learn more about jQuery). For now I have the following, which works perfectly when there is only one select menu to replace.

[See my example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9tC7/)

The problem is that when I add another drop down, I get the values from the two select inputs in one HTML list. This makes sense because the list is generated from default classes, but the problem is that I don't have any clue on how to sort the data.

I currently have the following code that alerts the data in the right order, but there I'm stuck. I don't now how to sort the data into two separate lists and apply these lists to the according, specific, parent element.

```
if($('.replaceDropdown').length > 0){
    $('.replaceDropdown').each(function(){
        select = $(this);
        select.after('<div class="replaceSelectContainer"><p>'+select.find('optgroup').attr('label')+'</p></div><div class="replaceSelectOptions"><ul class="selectOptionList"></ul></div>');
        options = $('option', select);
        alert(options.length);
        options.each(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
}
```

I suppose I should do something like `gather list items until options.length == max. If options.length == max { generate list items from the next select input }`. The only problem is that I don't have a clue how.

I'm hoping anybody can help me into the right direction.

Comment: not your question but you can ignore the `length` test, `each` will simply not run if the selector is empty..